# Create Cookie with cross domain in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, cookies

I have two laravel project with virtual host name 1) my.dev.com and 2) your.dev.com

I have create api for set cookie for cross domain and api is located at your.dev.com

```
Route::middleware('cors')->get('/hello', function () {
$cookie = Cookie::make('custom_cookie', 'hello_world', 10, "/", '.dev.com');
return response()->json('Hello worlds')->withCookie($cookie);
```

});

I make api call from `my.dev.com` and code is like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CORS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button">Call API</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("body").on("click","button",function () {
                $.get("http://my.dev.com/api/hello",function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

When I click Call API button from `my.dev.com` I get response `Hello worlds` but Cookie is not set `your.dev.com`

[image]

Even Cookie not set any `.dev.com` virtual host

**I want to set Cookie at `your.dev.com` from `my.dev.com`** with help of Ajax and code already posted here.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)

Comment: According to the duplicate, "all modern browsers respect the newer specification RFC 6265, and will ignore any leading dot, meaning you can use the cookie on subdomains as well as the top-level domain."

Comment: You might need to set the withCredentials flag for the AJAX request in this situation, I think.

Comment: I want set cookie using Ajax to another sub domain